# When to use Assert.Catch versus Assert.Throws in Unit Testing

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

I'm just looking for some examples of when it is appropriate to use Assert.Catch or Assert.Throws for asserting any exceptions thrown in unit testing. I know that I can use ExpectedException as well but I'm curious to know the difference between "Catch" and "Throws" in particular. Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The first line of the [documentation](https://github.com/nunit/nunit/wiki/Assert.Catch) seems pretty clear:

> `Assert.Catch` is similar to `Assert.Throws` but will pass for an exception that is derived from the one specified.

So use `Assert.Catch` if an exception that *derives* from the specified exception is valid (meaning that it too would be caught in an equivalent `catch` block).

The documentation for [Assert.Throws](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Assert.Throws) provides examples of both:

> ```
> // Require an ApplicationException - derived types fail!
> Assert.Throws(typeof(ApplicationException), code);
> Assert.Throws<ApplicationException>()(code);
>
> // Allow both ApplicationException and any derived type
> Assert.Throws(Is.InstanceOf(typeof(ApplicationException)), code);
> Assert.Throws(Is.InstanceOf<ApplicationException>(), code);
>
> // Allow both ApplicationException and any derived type
> Assert.Catch<ApplicationException>(code);
>
> // Allow any kind of exception
> Assert.Catch(code);
> ```